# sudden lost of access to esxi vSphere network

Tags: vmware-esxi, openvpn, linux-networking, vmware-vsphere, pfsense

Our lab setup consists of a vSphere Esxi server hosting some VMs. In front of VMs exists a pfSense router VM. All VMs are getting connectivity from router and additionally a openVPN server is set in order to have immediate access to internal LAN of VMs. However, tonight, during regular usage of network, all of a sudden everything went down! I was connected with openvpn to pfSense, doing some browsing while I was taking care of a process running in one of the VMs through ssh.

First indication was that suddenly WAN access was unavailable from my browser. On the same time, running process in VM started printing error messages, due to lack of internet connectivity. After less than a minute ssh access got interrupted and no other connection could be established with any of the VMs.

Immediately I thought that it would be probably an issue with the physical server, however VPN connection was still open! While I was connected to the same subnet with pfSense VM I was able to establish VPN connection but then no other connection towards VMs, pfSense control panel or esxi host could be established! Of course all of HTTP servers hosted in VMs where inaccesible either while connected to VPN or not.

Next idea to try was to access Esxi host 'physically' and try to figure out anything from its logs. I am not any expert but none of logs output seemed to be rerlevant to my issues. 
I tried unplugging and replugging ethernet cable and run network tests. Right after replugging, esxi was able to ping network default gateway but none of the external addresses. After some time ping to default gateway resulted to failure.

Of course a restart would be the best solution, however I would prefer to avoid it, if possible. I thought that since I could access VM network through openvpn maybe a workaround exists to access at least vsphere management console.

Any idea about what happened or how to trace the issue is greatly appreciated!

Thank you!